# Sum Formula acts weird when added text to it

Tags: excel, sum, worksheet-function

I have a macro and one of it's command is to create Formula to sum things up. Everything was fine until today when someone showed me problem.

Sum Function should give me: 36286,54. When function looks like this: `=SUM(I7:I128)` everything is ok but when I want to add some text to it like this: `=SUM(I7:I128) & " CZK"` it gives me: 36286,5399999999 CZK

I double checked values, nothing seems to be wrong... Problem is not caused by creating formula via macro, same problem appears doing it manually.
I investigated that those "99999999" at the end appears around 50th value when adding it using 'For Next' loop. 
Deleting some values makes "99999999" disappear but I have no idea why excacly those.

Everything was done on data below, any ideas what is wrong?

```
3 883,60
5 679,75
1 633,05
7 825,67
8 541,85
892,50
313,00
887,44
99,52
277,69
138,84
138,84
138,84
277,69
277,69
138,84
34,71
34,71
34,71
74,30
74,82
130,43
34,72
34,72
212,74
99,52
99,52
149,74
-2,74
212,74
212,74
212,74
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
13,88
34,71
34,71
69,42
31,24
31,24
31,24
31,24
31,24
31,24
31,24
31,24
41,65
41,65
41,65
10,41
10,41
20,83
20,83
20,83
20,83
20,83
13,88
3,47
6,94
15,62
57,10
190,90
10,67
34,71
138,84
138,84
277,69
55,50
34,71
86,78
86,78
166,61
13,88
67,83
117,39
117,39
67,69
62,48
8,68
135,37
104,13
69,42
69,42
14,75
15,62
15,62
15,62
31,24
46,86
62,48
26,10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely because of gradual errors introduced during the accumulation of all those value. I suspect that, if you instead used:

```
=SUM(I7:I128) - 36286,54
```

you'd get a very small, but non-zero, number. And indeed you do, if you examine the graphic below. To solve it, I'd suggest rounding the value explicitly before tacking on the currency indicator:

```
=ROUND(SUM(I7:I128),2) & " CZK"
```

Here's the proof of concept in Excel 2k13. With the C cell formulas being:

```
           C
1  =SUM(A1:A122)
2  =SUM(A1:A122) & " CZK"
3  =ROUND(SUM(A1:A122),2) & " CZK"
4  =C1-36286.54
```

The results is:

[image]

So you can see from C4 that the error between the *actual* value and the displayed value is about `0.00000000008`, a vanishingly small percentage.

As to *why* that happens, according to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687869%28v=office.15%29.aspx), Excel uses standard IEEE754 data types under the covers and it's a well known issue that those numbers do *not* have infinite precision.

Why it seems to work when you *don't* append a string, I don't know. Maybe Excel does some more intelligent rounding of sums at the end (perhaps based on the input data characteristics) when you're not forcing the type to be coerced to a string.

In any case, the explicit rounding seems to fix it so, being a pragmatist/realist,  I'd just go with that.

Comment: ...but why those errors appears? Is something wrong with my numbers, method of input or what it is? For me it looks everything is done as it should but still outcome is not satisfing.

Comment: Trying to figure it out because this is important to not lose any digit - financial work...

Comment: @lowak, adding a hundred and twenty-odd values gave you an error of a ten-billionth of a CZK. Unless you're going to be adding up more than a trillion values, you're probably safe :-) In any case, I _always_ explicitly round in financial spreadsheets (and I suggest you do the same), just to be safe. I don't rely on the cell display format for that.

Comment: Right, it works. I just wonder why it even happened. Those data is exported from special Form. This Form does not allow to insert more than 2 digits after coma. So I was really suprised to see this. Your anwser provides a solution to my problem but I will wait a little more to see if someone might know the reason behind this.

Comment: @lowak, see the update, I found some details on MS' own site that details the formats they use internally.

Comment: Oh my... pretty tough stuff to read ;) I am programming enthusiast and I guess I need some more time to get through this. Anyway thank you for all the details.

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating a text string when you append "CZK", rather than rounding I would opt for the `TEXT` function. This way you can state exactly how you want your number being shown:

```
=TEXT(SUM(A1:A122),"0.00 CZK")
```

Would display

```
36286.54 CZK
```

Comment: Interesting, very interesting. I like it :)